# Что поставить: точку или запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания необходимо поставить в предложении перед словом "она"?

**По первому вопросу выступила воспитатель она рассказала о плане работы на год.**

Comment: А не хотите примерно так написать: _"По первому вопросу выступила воспитатель, **рассказавшая** о плане работы на год"_?

Answer (score 1):

Возможны варианты...

Я бы ограничилась точкой: простенько и со вкусом.

Но не будет криминала ни в:

запятой;

точке с запятой;

тире.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты зависят от контекста и стиля, причем меньше всего подходит точка с запятой.

Еще один вариант забыли (один из  нейтральных): **По первому вопросу выступила воспитатель, рассказав о плане работы на год.**

Comment: По первому вопросу «О плане работы на год» выступила воспитатель N.

Answer (score 0):

Это сложное бессоюзное предложение с изъяснительными отношениями между частями. В этом случае нормативным знаком будет двоеточие или тире:

> По первому вопросу выступила воспитатель: она рассказала о плане работы на год.
>
> По первому вопросу выступила воспитатель   —  она рассказала о плане работы на год.

**См: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник. М., 2010. С. 261-262.**

Answer (score 0):

Если задача стоит так, что ничего менять нельзя, кроме знаков препинания, то  самым естественным знаком будет точка. Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> По первому вопросу повестки дня с докладом «Об итогах работы ОАО «XXX» за 2002 год и задачах Общества на 2003 год» выступил Генеральный директор XXX X. X.. В начале своего выступления XXX X.X. доложил акционерам, что ....….. [Протокол годового общего собрания (2003)]
>
> С докладом по первому вопросу выступил председатель Госплана СССР Н. К. БАЙБАКОВ. Докладчик подчеркнул, что... [Наши планы — шаги к коммунизму // «Вперед» (Калязинский р-н Калининской обл.), 1967]
>
> С докладом по этому вопросу выступил президент АМРОС, генеральный директор Богословского алюминиевого завода ― филиала ОАО «ОАЛ» А.В. Сысоев. Он отметил, что...  [В интересах работодателей и рабочих (2004) // «Металлы Евразии», 2004.01.23]